# rgbdslam on electric, compiling error

Tags: slam, navigation, rosmake, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hez guys,
I am trying to compile rgbdslam following this guide on ROS electric:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam_electric

eveything goes well, until, when compiling rgbdslam it happens that these errors come out:

```
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/petrinif/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121030-121118
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
['rgbdslam']                         
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished >> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished >> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished >> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished >> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished >> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished >> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished >> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished >> rosparam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished >> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished >> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished >> rosnode [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished >> eigen [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished >> cminpack [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished >> flann [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished >> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished >> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished >> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished >> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished >> g2o [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished >> rosbagmigration [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished >> rostopic [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Finished >> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished >> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished >> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished >> pcl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished >> visualization_msgs [ make ]                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished >> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished >> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished >> rgbdslam [ make ]                                      
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbdslam: 0.6 sec ]           [ 1 Active 52/53 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
  cd ann2fig ; make linux-g++
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
  make targets \
    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \
    "C++ = g++" \
    "CFLAGS = -O3" \
    "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \
    "RANLIB = true"
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
  make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'.
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2'
  
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:159 (find_package):
    Could not find module FindEigen.cmake or a configuration file for package
    Eigen.
  
    Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindEigen.cmake or set Eigen_DIR to the
    directory containing a CMake configuration file for Eigen.  The file will
    have one of the following names:
  
      EigenConfig.cmake
      eigen-config.cmake
  
  
  
  Eigen package was not found. This is OK FOR ROS ELECTRIC, bad for fuerte
  
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qtros.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_graph_manager.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_glviewer.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam and will be generated later
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/petrinif/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121030-121118/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished 
and the compiling process gets aborted. It looks like some files are missing but how do I fix this? I tried to look in google but no clue...
I additionally found this in the log output:

mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package rgbdslam
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findg2o.cmake or a configuration file for package
  g2o.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findg2o.cmake or set g2o_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for g2o.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    g2oConfig.cmake
    g2o-config.cmake




------------------------------------------------------------------

Compiling SiftGPU...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'
mkdir -p ../../../build/siftgpu
mkdir -p ./bin 
ln ../data/ -d -s -f
ar rcs ./bin/libsiftgpu.a ../../../build/siftgpu/FrameBufferObject.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GlobalUtil.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGLSL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ShaderMan.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftPyramid.o ../../../build/siftgpu/PyramidGL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftMatch.o
g++ -o ./bin/libsiftgpu.so ../../../build/siftgpu/FrameBufferObject.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GlobalUtil.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGLSL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ShaderMan.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftPyramid.o ../../../build/siftgpu/PyramidGL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftMatch.o -lGLEW -lglut -lIL -lGL -lX11 -I../include -fPIC -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L./bin -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pthread   -march=native -mfpmath=sse -shared -fPIC
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'

------------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------------------------------------------------

Compiling GICP...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2'
cd src ; make linux-g++
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src'
make targets \
    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \
    "C++ = g++" \
    "CFLAGS = -O3" \
    "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \
    "RANLIB = true"
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src'
cd test ; make linux-g++
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
make targets \
    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \
    "C++ = g++" \
    "CFLAGS = -O3" \
    "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \
    "RANLIB = true"
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
cd sample ; make linux-g++
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
make targets \
    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \
    "C++ = g++" \
    "CFLAGS = -O3" \
    "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \
    "RANLIB = true"
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
cd ann2fig ; make linux-g++
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
make targets \
    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \
    "C++ = g++" \
    "CFLAGS = -O3" \
    "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \
    "RANLIB = true"
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/petrinif/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2'
```

I downloaded g2o and could ros-install it but how should I proceed next? I do not know how to set this CMAKE_MODULE_PATH and I cannot find Findg2o.cmake in my g2o directory (and subdirectories)..

HELP!

Best

Flavio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46669/rgbdslam-on-electric,-compiling-error/) by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-24**:
Probably a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/46048/couldnt-find-executable-named-rgbdslam/

**Comment by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on 2012-10-24**:
You're right...same question...sorry. Should I delete mine?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-10-24**:
Thanks anyway, that pointed me to the original question, which I now answered. However, in both your cases, the relevant info is missing from your output snippet.

**Comment by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on 2012-10-29**:
Uhm...i posted it now...can this help? This EIGEN thing is a little bit weird to me...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-30**:
Please post the complete output. All the warnings listed above are actually expected and normal. The actual error must be somewhere else.

**Comment by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on 2012-10-30**:
Okay..hmm now that's all...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-30**:
I can get the same message, but without configuration incomplete. Please check the complete log output of the build log: Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/petrinif/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121030-121118/rgbdslam/build_output.log

**Comment by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on 2012-10-30**:
I found some additional information and posted it! Btw, how can I format my post? I am really a newbie here!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-30**:
Use  tags or for code indent 4 spaces (or use the code button with 10101 on in).

**Comment by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on 2012-10-30**:
Thanks a lot, i got it working ;) woah, it is still quite mystical but...it works :D

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-11-21**:
One has to remove the libg2o from the ubuntu software center and do the modifications as mentioned by dornhege in the first answer..and it finally rosmake gives no errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, so the problem is that g2o could not be found.

Do you have that in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH when building? `roscd g2o` should get you there. If you type make, it should start downloaded files and building g2o.

The problem might be that RGBDSLAMs cmake file only finds this via a cmake script and if you cannot install `libg2o` on your system that fails.

Adding a `<depend package="g2o" />` to RGBDSlam's manifest + removing the `find_package(g2o REQUIRED)` from CMakeLists.txt should solve this (given g2o builds).

I'm not sure if there is a better cross-distribution way.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that you have not read the preamble on http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam_electric and therefore checked out the fuerte version?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-31**:
That is very well possible as I also didn't read that and when I tested it now the revision for electric doesn't search g2o via find_package.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a complement to dornege's answer, i would like to point out that by doing what he says I got a "class redefinition error" which did not allowed me to compile. The solution at this problem is to uninstall the libg2o when compiling and installing the g2o package.

---

Originally posted by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) with karma: 33 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-11-21**:
This is great..One has to remove the libg2o from the ubuntu software center and do the modifications as mentioned by dornhege in the first answer..and it finally rosmake gives no errors...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-21**:
Have a look at Felix' answer. For electric, you'll need to check out the correct revision that should work out of the box.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-11-21**:
I was using fuerte..